# How to configure WSO2 API Manager for hourly logs

Tags: logging, wso2, api-manager

Can someone tell me how to configure WSO2 API Manager to use hourly logging files instead of daily?

Answer (score 0):

Try out using a `org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender` with a hourly format in the carbon logfile which is located at `repository/conf/log4j.properties`.  You'll need to configure the properties for the relevant appenders as:

```
log4j.appender.myAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.myAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
```

This will roll the logfile hourly.